# Analysis - Prove Continuity of $ f(x) = f(x), f²(x) = (f(x))², f³(x) = (f(x))³$

Tags: analysis, continuity

I've got a function 
$f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$.

$f², f³, . . .$ are pointwise defined as $f²(x) = (f(x))², f³(x) = (f(x))³, . . . .$

I have to prove/disprove

(i) $f$ is continuous so $f²$ and $f³$ are continuous

my attempt:

$f²(x) = (f(x))² = f(x) * f(x) \Rightarrow f²$ is continuous since factors are continuous

$f³(x) = (f(x))³ = (f(x))² * f(x) \Rightarrow f³$ is continuous since factors are continuous

also I have no idea how to prove/disprove:

(ii) $f²$ is continuous so $f$ is continuous

(iii) $f³$ is continuous so $f$ is continuous

Comment: For $(ii)$, let $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational and $-1$ otherwise, you can see that $f^2\equiv 1$ but $f$ is not continuous anywhere

Comment: The same worked if I let $f(x) = 1$ when $x$ is even and $-1$ otherwise, right? If e.g. $f$ was defined in $f : Q \rightarrow Q$

Comment: Yes(note that the function you gave is good even if the domain is all of the real numbers, it will be discontinuous at every even point, and not at every point), you can say that for every non empty dense(to be able to talk about continuity we need to be dense in R) set we have $f(x_0)=1,f(x_{\ne x_0})=-1$ as counter example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) Your attempt is correct.

**Hints**

ii) Think about a piecewise constant function which isn't continuous but whose square is constant.

iii) Use the function $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ to prove that the assertion is true.

(Moreover, why using the function $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ can't work in ii)?)